# Conditional statement not working in function

Tags: functions, conditional-content

Why doesnt this work ?  I am trying to selectively load scripts but the second if statement is not loading them where it should.

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js', false, '1.5');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

            if (in_category('41') )  {
            wp_register_script('validator', '/wp-content/themes/myTheme/library/jquery.validationEngine.js', array('jquery'), '2.0', false);
            wp_enqueue_script('validator');

            wp_register_script('vEngine', '/wp-content/themes/myTheme/library/jquery.validationEngine-en.js', array('validator'), '2.0', false);
            wp_enqueue_script('vEngine');
            }

    }   


}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

If I remove the second if statement for that category it works but I want to restrict it to a single category or even an is_single('123')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: It does not load the validator scripts

Comment: change 'init' to 'wp_print_scripts'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're doing this too early. The loop isn't setup yet when `init` is run, so you need to hook it somewhere else. `wp_print_scripts` and `wp_print_styles` or `get_header` are always nice choices. ;-)

Comment: Or even better would be the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook... :)

Answer (score 1):

I poked around, and it seems that the Codex reference that you can use conditional tags like `is_category()` in the `init` hook is incorrect.  However, this code *does* work just fine:

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js', false, '1.5');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }   
}
function my_scripts() {
    if (in_category('41') )  {
        wp_register_script('validator', '/wp-content/themes/myTheme/library/jquery.validationEngine.js', array('jquery'), '2.0', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('validator');

        wp_register_script('vEngine', '/wp-content/themes/myTheme/library/jquery.validationEngine-en.js', array('validator'), '2.0', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('vEngine');
        }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

Comment: Your `wp_print_scripts` is missing an `s` ... ;)

Comment: Too many rapid-fire edits ... It's been a long day :-)